# Error in results while executing gauss elimination program

Tags: c++

In codeblocks, the result of gauss elimination is showing nan and inf for some input and give right solution of some input even though upper triangular matrix of some input is showing nan or inf for the same program. i am not getting where i am missing.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
#include<cmath>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
float a[10][10],b[10],temp,x[10]={0};
int i,j,k,n,m;
cout<<"enter order of matrix";
cin>>m>>n;
cout<<"\n enter the elements of a matrix";
for(i=0;i<m;i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<n;j++)
        cin>>a[i][j];
}
cout<<"\n matrix is";
for(i=0;i<m;i++)
{       cout<<"\n";
    for(j=0;j<n;j++)
        cout<<a[i][j]<<"  ";
}
// upper triangular matrix
for(k=0;k<m;k++)
{
    for(i=k+1;i<m;i++)
        {   temp=a[i][k]/a[k][k];
            for(j=0;j<n;j++)
                {a[i][j]=a[i][j]-temp*a[k][j];
        }
}
}
cout<<"\n the gauss elimination matrix is";
for(i=0;i<m;i++)
{   cout<<"\n";
    for(j=0;j<n;j++)
        cout<<a[i][j]<<"  ";
}
// values of variables
for(i=(m-1);i>=0;i--)
{   temp=0;
    for(j=0;j<m;j++)
       temp=temp+a[i][j]*x[j];
     x[i]=(a[i][m]-temp+a[i][i])/a[i][i];
}
cout<<"\n the values of variables are";
for(i=0;i<m;i++)
{       cout<<"\n";
        cout<<x[i]<<"  ";
}
}
```

Comment: and please give the reason also with the answer so that i can clear my some basics

Comment: What are your inputs? I think that the problem is because of division by zero.

Comment: Give examples of the "some input" and the corresponding output.  But as Cool Guy says, divide by zero is probable: you're dividing by `a[k][k]` so a zero on the main diagonal is likely to cause problems.

Answer (score 1):

In your comments (after correcting the bug I mentioned in your original post) you described this input matrix

```
1 -2  -6  12
2  4  12 -17
1 -4 -12  22
```

which produces this upper triangle:

```
1  -2  -6   12  
0   8  24  -41  
0   0   0  -0.25
```

In the original, you should observe the first and third rows are contradictory:  Double all the coefficients of the unknowns but the right hand side is not doubled.  That means the system has no solution.  In the upper triangle form, that same problem has been compressed into the third row:  Zero times each unknown adds up to nonzero, so the third unknown is -INF and the other two can't be computed in any meaningful way.

Then you tried this matrix

**0** 2 1 -8
1 **-2** -3 0
-1 1 **2** 3
Notice I marked the main diagonal in bold.  You are dividing by the main diagonal, so that first zero wrecks the whole process.  That is what I meant in my first answer about needing to resequence to avoid divide by zero.

Your first example can't be solved.  No resequence would eliminate the contradiction between the first and third rows.

Your second example can be solved by resequencing.

I added crude resequencing to your code:
(my whole change is the loop beginning `for(i=k; ;i++)` )

```
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
#include<cmath>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  float a[10][10],b[10],temp,x[10]={0};
  int i,j,k,n,m;
  cout<<"enter order of matrix";
  cin>>m>>n;
  cout<<"\n enter the elements of a matrix";
  for(i=0;i<m;i++)
  {
      for(j=0;j<n;j++)
      cin>>a[i][j];
  }
  cout<<"\n matrix is";
  for(i=0;i<m;i++)
  {       cout<<"\n";
      for(j=0;j<n;j++)
      cout<<a[i][j]<<"  ";
  }
  // upper triangular matrix
  for(k=0;k<m;k++)
  {
      for(i=k; ;i++)
      {
          if (i==m)
          {
              cout << "\nThe matrix is singular\n";
              return -1;
          }
          if (a[i][k] != 0)
          {
              for(j=0;j<n;j++)
                  std::swap( a[k][j], a[i][j] );
              break;
          }
      }
      for(i=k+1;i<m;i++)
      {   temp=a[i][k]/a[k][k];
          for(j=0;j<n;j++)
          {a[i][j]=a[i][j]-temp*a[k][j];
      }
  }
  }
  cout<<"\n the gauss elimination matrix is";
  for(i=0;i<m;i++)
  {   cout<<"\n";
      for(j=0;j<n;j++)
      cout<<a[i][j]<<"  ";
  }
  // values of variables
  for(i=(m-1);i>=0;i--)
  {   temp=0;
      for(j=0;j<m;j++)
    temp=temp+a[i][j]*x[j];
      x[i]=(a[i][m]-temp+a[i][i])/a[i][i];
  }
  cout<<"\n the values of variables are";
  for(i=0;i<m;i++)
  {       cout<<"\n";
      cout<<x[i]<<"  ";
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot :) but i am not getting one thing exactly that is " Zero times each unknown adds up to nonzero" actually i am chemical engr and i have read c++ earlier in 12 so new in c++ now.

Comment: The idea is that the matrix was used to represent a system of simultaneous equations.  The transformed matrix represents a different system of equations that has the same answers.  So the row in the matrix `0 0 0 -.025` represents the equation `0X+0Y+0Z=-0.25`.  We are looking at whether the whole system of equations can be solved.  But if we have a single equation that is self contradictory like that, then the system could not be solved regardless of the other equations.

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious bug is you forgot to modify `temp` in your loop

```
for(j=0;j<m;j++)
    a[i][j]*x[j];
```

That bug gives you garbage answers and hides the more fundamental flaw that you can't blindly take the input matrix in original sequence.  You need to resequence the matrix to avoid the divides by zero.

You might want to also detect the case in which no resequence of the matrix can avoid divide by zero (implying the original matrix was singular and the system cannot be uniquely solved).

Comment: actually it was by mistake i was just trying to remove the error so manipulate the program. same result error again

Comment: my inputs are for 3*4 matrix, inputs are 1 -2 -6 12 2 4 12 -17 1 -4 -12 22, i got right results that is 1 -2 -6 12 0 8 24 -41 0 0 0 -0.25 but for input with same 3*4 matrix 0 2 1 -8  1 -2 -3 0 -1 1 2 3 i got d same problem of nan and infinite